# RaphaelJS stripes into a SVG

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, svg, raphael

I am making a dynamic map, with AngularJS and RaphaelJS.

My whole SVG object is created into a directive ; and I would like to give colors to each area of the map.

For some regions, I would like to do stripes ; and I have been looking for long how to do, it looks like :

```
background-color: orange;
background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, transparent, transparent 5px, rgba(0,0,0,1) 5px, rgba(0,0,0,1) 10px);
```

[image: my pattern]

I would also make this pattern change on hover (black and red stripes), and to come back to black and orange stripes on mouse out.

However I realized that there is no equivalent of "repeating-linear-gradient" in RaphaelJS (right ?) and I don't really know how to do.

I am at least trying to do it with gradients, but it's not working **(the result with on mouse over is not the one expected. Why ?)**

here is my code into the directive :

```
var paper = new Raphael(element[0], 600, 600);

var attr = {
    fill: "#f5f5f5",
    stroke: "#222",
    "stroke-width": 1,
    "stroke-linejoin": "round"
};

var fr = {};
fr.area1 = paper.path("...").attr(attr).attr({href: "#"});
fr.area1 = paper.path("...").attr(attr).attr({href: "#"});
fr.area1 = paper.path("...").attr(attr).attr({href: "#"});
```

[...]

```
var state = area 3;

attr = {      
 fill: '45-' + color1 + '-' + color2,
 stroke: "#222"};

fr[state].attr(attr);


            (function(state) {

                var area = fr[state];

                area[0].style.cursor = "pointer";
                area[0].onmouseover = function() {

                    area.animate({
                        fill: '45-' + color3 + '-' + color2,
                        stroke: "#222"
                    }, 10);
                    area.toFront();
                };

                area[0].onmouseout = function() {
                    area.animate({
                        fill: '45-' + color1 + '-' + color2,
                        stroke: "#222"
                    }, 300);
                    area.toFront();
                };
            })(state);
```

Thank you,

Comment: Think it could be more useful to break it down onto a jsfiddle highlighting the particular problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animated gradients seem to [not be supported](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/issues/192) by RaphaelJS. You have to call animate with 0 ms to avoid having a black flash effect during the animation. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gR8Kd/1/) of your working example.

To achive the stripped effect you can use this function (modified version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14543112/2712478)):

```
function gradientString(colors, step) {
    var gradient = '45-' + colors[0],
        stripe = false,
        len = colors.length,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < 100/step; i += 1) {
        gradient += '-' + colors[i % len] + ':' + i * step + '-' + colors[(i+1) % len] + ':' + i * step;
    }

    return gradient;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dgu8Q/2/) using this function to achive the stripes and behavior you want.